# Rails: Get Country (or any other) attribute of 'Users where city is unique'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, activerecord, hash

I'm trying to make a list of unique cities and their countries, that my Users are from, like this:

```
United States - Boston
United States - New York
United States - San Francisco
United Kingdom - London
United Kingdom - Manchester
France - Paris
France - Lyon
```

(there are many users that are from the same place)

(City and Country are just fields in the User model that are populated using reverse geocoding)

I can get the list of cities into an array using this

```
User.pluck(:city).uniq
```

But how can I add the country name from each user record into the array/hash, so I can build my list as above?

Comment: How are your models and relations set up?

Comment: I hope only the User model is relevant here - country and city are just fields in User, that are populated using the geocoder gem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should do it:

```
User.select("country, city").uniq
```

This should return an array of `User` objects where only `country` and `city` is populated.
Then you can map it into something you need, i.e.:

```
User.select("country, city").uniq.map { |u| "#{u.country} - #{u.city}" }
```

for instance...

**UPDATE**

Answering your comment:
Yes, you can just add the lat and lng fields you need like so:

```
# remember afterwards to only access the fields you're actively selecting here,
# otherwise you'll get an exception
@users = User.select("country, city, lat, lng").uniq.map { |u| { country: u.country, city: u.city, lat: u.lat, lng: u.lng } }
```

For easy use add a method to your `User` model that returns a string as you need it, i.e.:

```
def country_city
  "#{country} - #{city}"
end
```

And in your view(s) you can use the [`collection_select`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper method to only use the fields you want (by using the new method in the model) for your select but still have the `lat` and `lng` fields in the hash-array.

```
collection_select(:name_of_view_instance, :name_of_select_field, @users, :id, :country_city)
```

This gives you an HTML output like the following:

```
<select name="name_of_view_instance[name_of_select_field]">
  <option value="1" selected="selected">United States - Boston</option>
  <option value="2">United States - New York</option>
  <option value="3">United States - San Francisco</option>
  <!-- and so on -->
</select>
```

See the documentation of the helper method at above link.

Comment: works, thank you! is it possible to map other user attributes into the hash, but for them not be involved in the select? e.g. the latitude and longitude co-ordinates in something like this: User.order('country asc').select("country, city").uniq.map { |u| { country: u.country, city: u.city, lat: u.lat, lng: u.lng }} ?